# How to solve Apache2 error that keeps coming during start up

Tags: apache2, 15.10

I'm facing this error that keeps coming at the start up and throughout the on time of my machine. I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 dual boot.

[image]

Is there any solution to this error?

Answer (score 0):

Could this possibly be related to PHP rather than Apache2? I see people reporting exactly this [over at php.net](https://news-web.php.net/php.bugs/193068). The bug report there lists a reproduction script; maybe you did something similar in one of your scripts?

Also, I should mention (even though your question was posted a long time ago) that [Ubuntu 15.10 is end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). Please upgrade if you did not do already.